# Convert CGPoint between iPhone & CA planes

Tags: iphone, core-animation, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform, catiledlayer

I have a UIView subclass that I'm drawing a PDF onto (using a CATiledLayer).  I also need to draw on a specific region of that PDF, however the coordinate plane of the CATiledLayer when using CG to draw is way screwy.

See image:
[image]

I have a point (200,200), that I need to convert to the CATiledLayer's coordinate system, which is the 2nd plane shown above.  I've tried doing this with some transforms, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I had to do (using the example points/plane above):

```
//rotatation origin
CGPoint rotateOrigin = CGPointMake(0,0);
//rotatation transform
CGAffineTransform translateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(rotateOrigin.x, rotateOrigin.y);
//rotate the plane 90 degrees
float radians = 90 * (M_PI / 180);
CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);   CGAffineTransform customRotation = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat( CGAffineTransformInvert(translateTransform), rotationTransform), translateTransform);

CGAffineTransform m1 =  CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGPoint startPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(CGPointMake(200,200),m1);   
//rotated point
CGPoint rotatedPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(startPoint, customRotation);
//final rotated point- after adjusting for the rotation
rotatedPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(rotatedPoint, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(500,-500));
```